# ユーザ指定のファイル名に一致するディレクトリエントリ上のファイル名を得るには？

Tags: python

OS とファイルシステムにより、case insensitive であったり、いわゆる全角と半角の同一視であったり、Unicode 正規化などによって、ディレクトリエントリ上のファイル名と完全に一致していなくても特定のファイルを指定できることがありますが、ユーザの指定したファイル名から、これに一致する実際のディレクトリエントリ上のファイル名を得る方法がありますでしょうか。

```
% touch A.txt                         
% ls   
A.txt
% wc a.txt                             
       0       0       0 a.txt
```

例として、ディレクトリエントリ上のファイル名は A.txt ですが、ユーザが a.txt を指定してもこのファイルにアクセスできてしまいます。この状態のとき、ユーザが入力（指定）した a.txt から実際のファイル名 A.txt を得る方法になります。

力技として、ファイル名からディレクトリを得て、os.scandir() で読み出してチェックすることも考えましたが、ファイル名の一致判定の方法が思いつきませんでした。i-node で判定するとハードリンクで違うファイル名にも一致してしまいます。

python に限りませんが、ファイルシステムや OS (Win, mac, Linux/Unix) に依存しない方法がないでしょうか。

Comment: 確認ですが、与えられたファイル名についてOS依存の処理を再現してファイルを探したい(case insensitiveならcase insensitive、case sensitiveならcase sensitive)のではなく、常にcase insensitiveに探したいということでしょうか？

Comment: 探したいわけではなくて、ユーザーが指定したファイル名がOS依存、ファイルシステムやマウントオプション依存の処理によって特定のファイルにマッチする場合に、そのファイルのディレクトリエントリ上の名前を知りたいのです。（マッチしないのなら単にエラー）
そもそもの動機としては macOS 13 の Unicode 正規化バグを自分で調べたいというのが発端です。Finder で触ると NFD もどき？に、cp や mv で触ると NFC に変化してしまうのですが、特定のファイルの今の名前を確認できないものかと。

Comment: 上位ディレクトリからディレクトリエントリを読み出すことはできるのですが、ファイルがたくさんあるとかなり使いにくいので、ユーザが指定した文字列 a.txt にマッチするファイル A.txt のファイル名を読み出す方法か、ディレクトリから A.txt を含むファイル名一覧を読み出したときに、そのOS・ファイルシステムでは文字列 a.txt はこれにマッチすると判定する方法があれば、という次第です。

Comment: ファイル名だけでいいんですか？　ディレクトリ名とかも Case sensitive/insensitive だったりしますし、セパレータも backslash / slash で異なったりします。 `../Foo/bar.txt` の正規化パスは `..\\FOO\\BAR.txt` とかなったりしてほしいですか？

Comment: 躓いているのは単独のファイル名です。これには単独のディレクトリ名も含みます。階層構造を順に処理していく、セパレータを得る等は、別の問題で、これは自分でなんとかできると考えています。

Comment: パス名正規化の問題と捉えるべきかもしれません。文字列と実際のファイルを一意のパス名に正規化する方法があれば、文字列比較で可能なはずです。ただ、case insensitive や全角半角 insensitive、Unicode正規化まで考慮したパス名正規化の手段があるかどうかが問題です。

Comment: Windows 10 ビルド 17107 以降ではディレクトリ単位で case insensitive/sensitive を切り替えることができると知りました。`c:\dir\subdir\file.html` で subdir 以下が case sensitive だとすれば、ディレクトリごとに考慮して、例えば `C:\DIR\subdir\file.html` に正規化する必要がありそうです。<https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity>

Comment: 例えばこんな記事が応用できるかもしれません。[Case sensitive path comparison in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6710511/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

> ファイルシステムや OS (Win, mac, Linux/Unix) に依存しない方法がないでしょうか。

私が知る限り、統一的な方法はないかと思います。

以下、Python で使えるかどうかわからない情報です。

- macOS は [`NSString` の `fileSystemRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414559-filesystemrepresentation?language=objc) を呼んでからディレクトリ内のファイル一覧と `fnmatch(..., FNM_CASEFOLD)` で比較すればいいかもしれません。
- Windows は、入力ファイル名で [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) を呼ぶと結果の `WIN32_FIND_DATA::cFileName` にはディスク上の名前が入っていた記憶があります。